# what should i use in this case row filter or select query

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable, rowfilter

I am writing a program to filter the data in the given data table in csharp that can filter differnet  channels based on their type and  what user wants cattegorized as news,entertainment and other etc but am getting exception when user first clicks on other channels rather then first to display all the channels.

A column named 'channel_id' already belongs to this DataTable

design image : [image]

i have tried using this by applying the row filter in the default view of the datatable.

this is the complete code with all the functions

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace vp_practice
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        DataTable dttvchannel = new DataTable();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void filldata()
        {
            //Adding columns
            dttvchannel.Columns.Add("channel_id", typeof(int));
            dttvchannel.Columns.Add("channel_name");
            dttvchannel.Columns.Add("Type");
            //Adding Rows
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "Bol tv", "News");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "geo news", "News");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "Hum tv", "entertainment");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "Ary new", "News");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "catoon network", "catoons");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "Masala tv", "non tv ");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "Ary entertainment", "entertainment ");
            dttvchannel.Rows.Add(1, "dunya tv", "empter");
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            filldata();
            listBox1.DataSource = dttvchannel;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "channel_name";
            label2.Text = dttvchannel.DefaultView.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dttvchannel.DefaultView.RowFilter ="Type Like '%News'" ;
            label2.Text = dttvchannel.DefaultView.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dttvchannel.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Type like '%entertainment'";
            label2.Text = dttvchannel.DefaultView.Count.ToString();
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dttvchannel.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Type Not in('News','entertainment')";
        }
    }
}
```

if the user clicks the other buttons rather than the show all the program should display the channels accordingly

Comment: Every time you click the button you call again filldata and this method tries to add again the columns to the instance of dttvchannel. Why don't you call _filldata_ just one time in the constructor after the INitializeComponent?

Comment: Looking better I think you can move all the code in the button1_click to the form constructor. You don't need anymore that button

Comment: okay thats fine but the show all button is a requirement for the application i means show all button should display all the channels whenever user clicks it

Comment: Then just use that button1 to set the RowFilter="" to remove the filter (if any) and show everything. Initializing your data in the constructor or in form_load has the added benetit to not require an initial click to show the default data set